# How can I construct in $\Gamma$ an structure of Directed Set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $\Gamma$ is a uncountable set. It is possible to give $\Gamma$ an structure of an directed set? For an definition of directed set, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set).

Comment: Just any set $\Gamma$? Or something specific? What do you mean by "construct"? You can always well-order $\Gamma$ (unless you have qualms about applying the axiom of choice).

Comment: I was trying to clarify the intentions because "construct" in the title and the axiom of choice don't go very well together. No offense intended :-) In a specific context there might be a natural order on $\Gamma$ better adapted to the problem than what pulling some tricks with the axiom of choice would give you.

Comment: Ok, no problem, I deleted my comment and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course.

Using the axiom of choice you can always linearly order $\Gamma$, or even well-order it.

If you want something more exotic, and interesting, $|\Gamma|=|\text{Fin}(\Gamma)|$, i.e. the set of all finite subsets of $\Gamma$ has the same size as $\Gamma$. You can order $\text{Fin}(\Gamma)$ by inclusion, and see this is indeed a directed set, then pull the order back to $\Gamma$.

Equally you can do all sort of crazy shticks, order $\Gamma$ with $\leq_1$ and with $\leq_2$ to be two linearly ordered sets, then consider their pointwise product $\leq$ on $\Gamma\times\Gamma$: $$(a,b)\leq(c,d)\iff a\leq_1 c\textbf{ and }b\leq_2 d.$$

This is not linearly ordered, but you can show this is a directed set. Again the axiom of choice comes in handy when you want to show that $\Gamma\times\Gamma$ has the same size as $\Gamma$ to allow pulling this order back to $\Gamma$ itself.